# Chipkit compatibility with Arduino

Tags: arduino, kits

I am looking at the [Digilent Chipkit](http://digilentinc.com/Products/Catalog.cfm?NavPath=2,892&Cat=18) boards.  What compatibility issues have any of you run across?  There are too many weasel words in the descriptions...

- Compatible with ***many*** existing Arduino™ code examples, reference materials and other resources.
- Pin-out compatibility with ***many*** existing Arduino™ shields that can operate at 3.3V

Anyone familiar with any issues using regular Arduino code on these boards (via the custom programmer/UI, of course)?

I like that there are more I/O pins and features exposed.  And though I do not need it today, the idea of increased performance could become important down the road as well.

Also, FWIW, it looks like Digilant's custom shields are NOT compatible with  standard Arduino boards, as they appear to use these extended I/O capabilities.

Comment: No experience thereof, but: [Their forum](http://www.chipkit.org/forum/) should be of use, and [their Wiki page](http://www.chipkit.cc/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) looks useful.

Comment: I wrote an article about it here: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/why-bother-with-an-arduino-uno-any-more

Comment: Majenko, I really like your write-up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work well with most basic sketches and examples you will find on the internet that do not do too many AVR specific things. The arduino environment is effective at hiding the details of the actual processor from you, but it does not mandate that separation. You are still welcome to import the chip-specific header files and directly change specific registers, access pins directly, and interact with the chip on a much lower level. Any code that uses the avr specific headers will not port cleanly to a pic system without modifications.